How to align 2D artists with 3D points (what is the correct coordinate transform)?
In this figure:

Red circles are 3D points plotted with Axes3D.scatter(). They have a 3D position. Numbers in their bbox are plotted with Axes3D.add_artist(). They are derived from mpl.text.Text, meaning they are 2D objects with fixed viewport coordinates. I want the figures to be aligned with the circles, so the instances are passed the corresponding 3D coordinates, up to them to draw themselves at the correct viewport coordinates.
This example has no real purpose, this is only to practice 3D in Matplotlib and how 2D and 3D widgets can be aligned, regardless of the point of view. I had a hard time reading Matplotlib 3D documentation, It seems there is no real starting point to progressively learn how to use the 3D toolkit. My current attempt is somehow working, but this is more by chance than by a logical method.
I think I need to override the draw method of the 2D text and project the 3D coordinates into the 2D viewport plane, but I cannot do it correctly.
I had to artificially scale the 2D positions to better match the circles just in order to create the image above. This scaling has no other justification, and without it the figures don't match the circles at all. Can you help me understand what is the correct method?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
    
class Text2d_upd(mpl.text.Text):
    text_kw = dict(fontsize=12, ha='center', va='center')
    bbox = dict(boxstyle='circle', pad=0.3, facecolor='turquoise', alpha=0.5)

    def __init__(self, x, y, z, *args, **kwargs):
        self.p = x, y, z
        kwargs = kwargs | self.text_kw
        super().__init__(x, y, *args, bbox=self.bbox, **kwargs)

    def draw(self, renderer):
        # Convert 3D coords to 2D view coords
        M = self.axes.M
        x, y, z = proj3d.proj_transform(*self.p, M)

        # Shift artist to 2D position
        k = 5.4 # <-- non-justified scaling
        self.set_position((k*x+0.5, k*y+0.5))
        super().draw(renderer)


a = np.pi/4
r = 3

# 2D rotation matrix
c, s = np.cos(a), np.sin(a)
M = np.array([[c, -s], [s, c]])

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', zlabel='z')

# Plot
v = np.array([r, 0])
for i in range(8):
    p = (*v, 0)
    ax.scatter(*p, ec='red', fc='none', s=20**2)

    t = Text2d_upd(*p, f'{i}', transform=ax.transAxes)
    ax.add_artist(t)

    v = M @ v

ax.set_zlim(-r, r)
ax.set(aspect='equal')

